# How to call windows application from Outlook 2010 on hyperlink click in email body

Tags: windows-7, outlook-2010

Outlook 2010, Windows 7. Upon receiving email we want underlined text

application_path\application par1 par2

to act as hyperlink . When we click on it either the same proxy application is called which accepts value of hyperlink and launches respective application with parameters 
OR the application somehow called directly as if it is called from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to register a custom URL protocol handler and use the correct URL syntax to invoke the app. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx for more details.